# Magento: getSingleton('customer/session') doesn't return information when called via SOAP

Tags: magento, session, soap, singleton

I am currently trying to get back customer data after submitting an order and capturing the checkout_submit_all_after event with an Observer. If I make the order via the frontend, `Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')` and `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')` **ran inside the observer** give me a wealth of information, however when I make an order via SOAP, these methods returns nothing. I also tried `Mage::helper('customer')->getCustomer()` but it didn't return anything either.

Is there another way I can obtain the data of the last submitted order? Specifically I need the customer from the session and the last order id ala `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId()`.

Comment: Looking at the code which generates checkout_submit_all_after event, the $observer variable should have data related to the order. However this is also empty.. Currently researching why.

Comment: Ok got orderid from $observer['order']->getIncrementId(). Funny how print_r wasn't showing anything though..

Comment: Almost there.. now the only problem is that I can't get the email from either the order or quote objects. Going into the API where it builds the quote _prepareGuestQuote it uses ->setCustomerEmail($quote->getBillingAddress()->getEmail(), however this is blank! I even tried to cheat by setting 'email' in the array of values sent to SOAP's shoppingCartCustomerAddresses method, but it did't work. I know that email isn't saved on guest purchases, however the email should at least be available until the end of the order!! Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this nonsense: the quote->customer_email field is originally populated with the email, then after setting the addresses with the SOAP method 'shoppingCartCustomerAddresses', _prepareGuestQuote from Checkout/Model/Api/Resource/Customer.php OVERWRITES this with "$quote->getBillingAddress()->getEmail()). Which has to be blank! Why? Well check out the wsdl definition of the address object:

```
         <complexType name="shoppingCartCustomerAddressEntity">
            <all>
                <element name="mode" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="address_id" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="firstname" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="lastname" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="company" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="street" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="city" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="region" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="region_id" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="postcode" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="country_id" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="telephone" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="fax" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="is_default_billing" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0"/>
                <element name="is_default_shipping" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0"/>
            </all>
        </complexType>
```

Do you see an 'email' field in there? I sure don't!
So now I have to override the thing just to make it FUNCTIONAL. Seriously Magento, wtf?